# MvvmCross + Xamarin.Forms: different page layouts for Tablets and Phones

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

Is there a convenient way to use different page layouts for Tablets and Phones using MvvmCross + Xamarin.Forms?
Maybe something is implemented for this in MvvmCross?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, first you can adapt your pages, with specific values for Phone or Tablet, reusing the same XAML.

Example:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <Grid.ColumnSpacing>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
             Phone="20"
             Tablet="40"/>
 </Grid.ColumnSpacing>
  <Grid.RowSpacing>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
             Phone="10"
             Tablet="20"/>
  </Grid.RowSpacing>
  <Grid.Padding>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
             Phone="10, 10, 10, 0"
             Tablet="20, 20, 20, 0"/>
  </Grid.Padding>
  <!-- Grid Content -->
</Grid>
```

Another option would be, having two different pages, one for tablet and one for phone:

```
 if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet || Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Desktop)
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new StoresTabletPage());
  else
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new StoresPage());
```

You can find more information [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/bringing-xamarin-forms-apps-to-tablets/)

Comment: In MvvmCross you cannot push pages using MvxNavigationService. It has a ViewModel first navigation.